# Pagination in Wordpress home.php

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Pagination isn't working in a Wordpress blog. I've tracked the specific file responsible, to home.php.

The original blog page displays posts fine (10 at a time), however as mentioned pagination isn't working.

```
<?php
/**
Category Page
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div class="container-fluid blogs post-section" id="blogs">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
<?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?> 

<div class="category-posts">

<?php

$args = array(
    "post_type" => "post",
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "posts_per_page" => "10",
    "orderby" => "date",
    "order" => "DESC"
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="inner-post">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?><div class="thumbnail col-sm-4" style="background:none!important;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div><?php } ?>
<div class="abso custom_abso col-sm-8"><div class="inner-box">
<div class="date">
<?php 
$archive_year  = get_the_time('Y'); 
$archive_month = get_the_time('M'); 
$archive_day   = get_the_time('d'); 
?>
  <span class="month"><?php echo $archive_month; ?></span> <span class="day"><?php echo $archive_day; ?>,</span><span class="year"><?php echo $archive_year; ?></span>
</div>
<h2 style="margin-top:0;"><a  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmores">Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a></p>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif;
 ?></div>
<div class="pagination text-center">
<?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size' => 2 ) ); ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div></div></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Based on [this Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), I've updated the top of the file, to look like the following:

```
<div class="category-posts">

<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'cat'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'author_name'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'fields'           => '',
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>


<div class="col-sm-12">
```

This has worked, in that the pagination buttons work, however, only one post is displayed per page:

[image: Only one post displayed per page]

Any advice on how to display 10 posts per page?

Comment: When you say "pagination isn't working," what exactly happens? Pagination isn't being displayed? Pagination is displayed but pagination links don't seem to work?

Comment: Sorry - to be clear, pagination is displayed, but clicking any numbers just shows the content from page 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the following parameter 'paged'. It sets pagination query variable. The pagination is works as per this parameter.

```
 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
```

to the `$args`.

Comment: This should fix OP's problem. It would have been nice if you explained why, though.

Comment: I actually had previously tried this, but at that point it didn't work. Not sure if this was due to cache. I reverted to the previous version of the page and added the above. All now works as normal. Thanks!